# Why is my sklearn linear regression model producing perfect predictions?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to do multiple linear regression with sklearn and I have performed the following steps. However, when it comes to predicting y_pred using the trained model I am getting a perfect r^2 = 1.0. Does anyone know why this is the case/what's going wrong with my code?

Also sorry I'm new to this site so I'm not fully up to speed with the formatting/etiquette of questions!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Import and subset data
ml_data_all = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/User/Documents/RSEM/STADM/Coursework/Crime_SF/Machine_learning_collated_data.xlsx')
ml_data_1218 = ml_data_all[ml_data_all['Year'] >= 2012]

ml_data_1218.drop(columns=['Pop_MOE',
                               'Pop_density_MOE',
                                'Age_median_MOE',
                               'Sex_ratio_MOE',
                                'Income_median_household_MOE',
                               'Pop_total_pov_status_determ_MOE',
                                'Pop_total_50percent_pov_MOE',
                                'Pop_total_125percent_pov_MOE',
                               'Poverty_percent_below_MOE',
                                'Total_labourforceMOE',
                               'Unemployed_total_MOE',
                               'Unemployed_total_male_MOE'], inplace=True)

# Taking care of missing data
# Delete rows containing any NaNs
ml_data_1218.dropna(axis=0,
                   how='any',
                   inplace=True)

# DATA PREPROCESSING

# Defining X and y
X = ml_data_1218.drop(columns=['Year']).values
y = ml_data_1218['Burglaries '].values

# Encoding categorical data 
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

transformer = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[("cat", OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = transformer.fit_transform(X)
X.toarray()
X = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(X)

# Split into Training set and Test set
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)

# Feature scaling 
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
X_train.iloc[:,149:] = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train.iloc[:,149:])
X_test.iloc[:,149:] = sc_X.transform(X_test.iloc[:,149:])

# Fitting multiple linear regression to training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor = LinearRegression()
regressor.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predicting test set results
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: At first inspection, I cannot see anything wrong in your code. You should check if you may have *duplicates* in your initial data (before splitting); if this is the case, many test samples that are supposed to be unseen may have slipped in your training set, hence the unnaturally high performance (yes, I have seen it in practice :)

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for taking the time to check! Yeah, I can't figure out what's going wrong even though I've checked through the code a few times. I've checked for and removed duplicates but I'm still getting a perfect r^2

Comment: Can you try to plot your y and y_pred for both train and test data?

Comment: @nickthefreak Do you mean plot them against each other on a scatterplot?

Comment: @smalas exactly!  You should try this with different random seeds and different test/train splits, but the plot will help you understand the predicted values and whether the issue is with the regression, the data or the metric calculation.

Comment: @nickthefreak Yeah they are a perfect fit when I plot them on a scatterplot. I tried different test/train splits and random seeds and still getting a perfect r^2 for predictions.

Comment: @nickthefreak I am thinking that perhaps something went wrong with my data standardization, but I only have limited machine learning experience so I'm not sure what could have gone wrong

Comment: @smalas maybe, it's hard to tell without knowing the dataset. A good start would be to start without any scaling or data transformations. Good luck with the coursework!

Comment: @nickthefreak Thank you! Yeah, will probably try it without the scaling and see what happens :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nickthefreak Still having the same issue even if I don't do feature scaling. The mystery remains unsolved.

Answer (score 1):

So turns out it was a stupid mistake in the end: I forgot to drop the dependent variable (Burglaries) from the X columns haha, hence why the linear regression model was making perfect predictions. Now it's working (r2 = 0.56). Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

With regression, it's often a good idea to run a correlation matrix against all of your variables (IVs and the DV). Regression likes parsimony, so removing IVs that are functionally the same (and just leaving one in the model) is better for R^2 value (aka model fit). Also, if something is correlated at .97 or higher with the DV, it is basically a substitute for the DV and all the other data is most likely superfluous.

When reading your issue (before I saw your "Answer") I was thinking "either this person has outrageous correlation issues or the DV is also in the prediction data."